# Hibernate 3.6 + JPA2 + Guice-persist + Maven

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Is possible use Hibernate 3.6 + JPA2 + Guice-persist + Maven through maven?

I've tried a lot of setups, and it didn't work.

I've been noticed that hibernate-commons-annotations isn't needed anymore, but if exclude it, I got the `Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager` error.

At this moment, my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<name>Foo</name>
<description>bar. </description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!-- ~le propriedades com as versoes das coisas~ -->
<properties>
    <hibernateVersion>3.6.10.Final</hibernateVersion>
    <bval.version>0.4</bval.version>
</properties>

<!-- ~le dependencias~ -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- ~ le jsr303 ~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ~ le hibernate... ~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ~ le ehcache ~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ~ le cglib ~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>${guiceVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
        <version>${guiceVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
        <artifactId>bval-core</artifactId>
        <version>${bval.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
        <artifactId>bval-jsr303</artifactId>
        <version>${bval.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my persistence.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="scuv" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.digitaldoc.scuv.model.Produto</class>
    <class>br.com.digitaldoc.scuv.model.Cliente</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!-- Validation modes: AUTO, CALLBACK, NONE -->
    <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/SCUV"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgre"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <!-- ehcache second level cache config -->
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
      <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="META-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
      <!-- c3p0 connection pool config -->
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
     <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
      <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100"/>
      <!-- seconds -->
      <property name="c3p0.max_size" value="100"/>
      <property name="c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>
      <property name="c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>
      <property name="c3p0.timeout" value="100"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I inject my EntityManager with Guice... Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replace hibernate with EclipseLink. Not it works fine.